# Datarow and DataCell error

Tags: c#

I am trying to add my webpage data to DataGridView in C#.

I have successfully stored the webpage data (Source data) to a string called StrResults. Using Regex I have removed all tags. Now I need to move the content to DataGridView. Here i am getting error for DataRow and DataCell.

Here is my Code :

```
DataRow dr= new DataRow();  //Getting Error Here "Error 1   'System.Data.DataRow.DataRow(System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is inaccessible due to its protection level"
foreach (Match m in m1)
{ 
    String value=m.Value;
    String[] data=value.split(':');
    DataCell dc=new DataCell();      //Getting Error Here, "Error   2   The type or namespace name 'DataCell' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

    dc.value=data[1];
    dr.cell.add(dc);
}
dataGridView1.rows.add(dr);
```

I have added my current code below as suggested. Only one error is showing for DataCells

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

foreach (Match m in m1)
{
    String value = m.Value;
    String[] data = value.Split(':');
    DataCell dc = new DataCell();      //Getting Error Here
    dc.value = data[1];
    dr.Cell.add(dc);
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this instead of DataRow dr= new DataRow()

```
DataTable dtTable = New DataTable();

    DataRow r = dTable.NewRow()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `DataRow` that way. You should use `DataTable.NewRow()`

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
```

And there is no type named `DataCell` in `System.Data`. In fact, you can't add cells to your rows. You should add them to your `DataTable` as `DataColumn`s:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.ColumnName = "id";
table.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "name";
table.Columns.Add(column);

foreach (Match m in m1)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    String value=m.Value;
    String[] data=value.split(':');

    row["id"] = data[0];   // For example
    row["name"] = data[1]; 
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: This is perfect, how can add this data to datagridview?

Comment: You can use the `DataSource` property of `DataGridView`. You can find  a lot of samples and walkthroughs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx